# How to map query string to model data ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i heard from a write up that we can pass query string with `Html.BeginForm()` so i did this way

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { CustomerName = "joydev" }))
```

but when i post the form then it was not mapped to my model data.

### here is my viewmodel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<Movies> movies { get; set; }
    public List<Hobbies> hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

see my action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel oVm, string CustomerName)
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Success";
     return View(oVm);
}
```

i saw string CustomerName was empty and `oVm CustomerName` was null. just tell me where i made the mistake for which `CustomerName` is not passing as query string to action method. please guide me. thanks

### Edit

Some one said :- data is posted as query string. In action it is available through all three methods i.e. In Model, Action Parameter and through Request.QueryString.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl, string testparam)
        {

            string additionalParamValueFromQueryString = Request.QueryString["testparam"]; // Method 1
            string additionalParamValueFromModel = model.testparam; // Method 2
            string additionalParamValue = testparam; // Method 3
}
```

see the url http://forums.asp.net/p/2070398/5975252.aspx?p=True&t=635801707044672469

Comment: if `CustomerName` is a property on `MyViewModel`, why do you need it as a separate parameter?

Comment: for the time think customer name is not property of view model. just tell me how to pass query string with @Html.Beginform to action method?

Comment: See my edit 1 section too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { CustomerName = "joydev" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
```

Check the overload list for [BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.100).aspx). You're using

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

which changes the HtmlAttributes of the `<form>` tag, generating

```
<form action="Home/Index" CustomerName="joydev" method="POST"
```

you should use

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    FormMethod method
)
```

to generate (and send the value to the server)

```
<form action="Home/Index?CustomerName=joydev" method="POST"
```